# Sending mail from .NET project via outlook and receive notification when sent

Tags: .net, email, outlook, send

Assumptions:

1. Using .NET 2013 (C# / VB).
2. Mail client is Outlook (2010+).
3. Mail server is Exchange.

Questions:

1. Is there a way from a .NET project to directly send an email using some kind of Outlook object?
2. Can it be sent without showing a new window and having to press "send"?
3. Will the mail be saved to "Sent Items" folder if the "Send" process finishes successfully?
4. Will the process receive back an event / notification if the mail was successfully sent or if it produced an immediate error during "send" (i.e. SMTP server down).
5. Is there a built-in process (into the libraries that will be used) to detect if the mail was actually sent or it was returned back for some reason?

Comment: So what is your specific question?  Currently, this is too broad.

Comment: I've not tried it but could you not just use the SMTP client built into System.Net? I don't know for sure that it would add it to the Sent Items but  I would try that out first before trying to automate Outlook (which is a pain).

Comment: I thought i _was_ specific. I would like to send an email through Outlook so that it is saved to the Sent folder. Using the .NET email client will just send the mail, it will not save it to Outlook's Sent folder. Also, upon Send, i would like to be able to know if the Sent process was successful or not (so that implies a way to communicate with Outlook and somehow receive the result of the SendMail process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the message to be in the Sent Items folder, straight SMTP won't work. But you can use the Outlook Object Model or EWS.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I re-worded the original question so i guess your reply answers Q1 and Q3.

Comment: These is what I already answered - you need to use Outlook Object Model (or Extended MAPI or Redemption) or EWS to have a sent message in the Sent Items folder of the mailbox.